# Get map entries with matching keys using Stream API

Tags: java, hashmap, java-stream

I have an array of values

```
String [] str = { ONE, TWO, THREE };
```

and some key-value pairs stored in a map

```
Map<String, String> map;
```

How can I use the Stream API to get all entries from the map whose key is contained in the array?

Comment: Please show some effort, what have you tried so far? Where exactly have you difficulties solving this on your own? (see [help], [ask])

Comment: With Guava you can do `Map.filterKeys(map, Arrays.asList(str)::contains)`.

Comment: @shmosel I just looked up that method and stumble upon: “*The returned map is a live view of `unfiltered`*”. Do you really want to use a map where each key lookup implies a linear search through an array?

Comment: @Holger Depends on how it's used. You can easily copy it to a new map if necessary.

Comment: @shmosel sure, if the caller is aware of this subtlety. Might be worth noting that there’s also the standard API possibility, e.g. `result = new HashMap<>(map); result.keySet().retainAll(Arrays.asList( str));`, or even using the `retainAll` on the original map if it’s mutable and the old state not needed anymore, since JDK1.2…

Answer (score 1):

I assume that when you say you want the entries from this map, you mean the values
so here is how I would do it

```
    String[] str = {"ONE", "TWO", "THREE"};
    Map<String, String> map = <Your map's here>;

    List<String> values = Stream.of(str)
            .filter(map::containsKey)
            .map(map::get)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: You can avoid the duplicate lookup with `.map(map::get).filter(Objects::nonNull)`.

Comment: @shmosel but in either case, there is no correspondence between list indices and source array indices when you `filter`, which raises the question whether skipping elements not in the map actually is intended (compared to just store `null` in the list.

Answer (score 1):

If the map and the set of keys to remove are small, start with a copy of the map, and then modify it.

```
Map<String, String> filtered = new HashMap<>(map);
filtered.keySet().retainAll(Arrays.asList(str));
```

If the map is so much larger than the set of keys to remove that making a copy is undesirable, you can build a new map with only the correct entries:

```
Set<String> filter = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(str));
Map<String, String> filtered = map.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(e -> filter.contains(e.getKey))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to stream the array and collect the elements into a new map, with the keys being the elements and the values taken from your map for each key:

```
Map<String, String> result = Arrays.stream(str)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e, map::get));
```

This assumes all the elements of the array are keys in the map, and no duplicate elements on the array.

If you want to filter out elements that aren't keys of the map, use `filter` on the stream:

```
Map<String, String> result = Arrays.stream(str)
    .filter(map::containsKey)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e, map::get));
```

And if you have duplicate elements in the array:

```
Map<String, String> result = Arrays.stream(str)
    .filter(map::containsKey)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e, map::get, (o, n) -> o));
```

The last parameter `(o, n) -> o` is a merge function that is applied to values when there are duplicates keys on the map. In this case, the merge function keeps the old value and discards the new one.

Answer (score 1):

You didn’t specify the form of the result.

If you want the same map but only containing the specified keys, you can use

```
Map<String, String> map;
Map<String, String> result = new HashMap<>(map);
result.keySet().retainAll(Arrays.asList(str));
```

If the old state is not needed anymore and the map is mutable, you may apply the second statement to the `map` without creating a copy.

A solution always creating a new `Map` would be

```
Map<String, String> result = Arrays.stream(str)
    .collect(HashMap::new, (m, k) -> m.computeIfAbsent(k, map::get), Map::putAll);
```

---

If you just want an array containing values corresponding to the array containing the keys, you could use

```
String[] result = new String[str.length];
Arrays.setAll(result, ix -> map.get(str[ix]));
```

or

```
String[] result = Arrays.stream(str).map(map::get).toArray(String[]::new);
```